# Syncrhonize multiple api calls Android RxJava

Tags: android, rest, rx-java2, rx-android

I have an 2 API calls:

- Call1: `Observable<Product>` -> One returns a list of Products.
- Call2: `Observable<InfoProduct>` -> Other returns more info from a Product (given an ID) (the response doesn't contains the Id of the product)

What I need us to call the list of products, once I have it, call one by one the extra info from the second api call. Once I have all, I have to mnix all the data to get a list of "CompleteInfoProduct"

I'm able to get the info of the Call1, and I finally achieved get the list of more info products(call2). And here is the problem, I dont know how to "match" the call2, with a item of a call1.

Example simplified:

```
getProducts()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { response ->
            if (response.success) {
                val productsId = response.products.map { it.id }

                val obversableListMoreInfoProducts = mutableListOf<Observable<MoreInfoProductResponse>>()

                productsId.forEach { productId ->
                    obversableListMoreInfoProducts.add(
                            this.model.getMoreInfoProduct(productId)
                    )
                }

                val sub = Observable.merge(obversableListMoreInfoProducts)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .toList()
                        .subscribe { it ->
                            Logger.d("Size MoreInfoProducts: ${it.size}")
                            <HERE I HAVE THE LIST OF MORE INFO . THE PROBLEM IS THAT THIS MODDEL DONT HAVE THE ID OF THE PRODUCT, AND I DON'T KNWO HOW TO JOIN WITH IT>
                        }
                addSubscription(sub)
            }
        }
```

How can I synchronize and mix all the info?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution might look similar to this:

```kotlin
class SO64424129 {
    private fun getProducts(): Single<List<Int>> { // (1)
        return Single.just(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

    private fun getProductInfo(productId: Int): Single<String> { // (2)
        return Single.just("PI: $productId")
            .delay(Random().nextLong().rem(1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }

    fun getFullProducts(): Single<List<String>> {
        return getProducts()
            .flatMap { ids ->
                Observable.fromIterable(ids) // (3)
                    .flatMapSingle { productId ->
                        getProductInfo(productId)
                            .map {  productInfo -> "$productId $productInfo" } // (4)
                    }
                    .toList() // (5)
            }
    }
}

class SO64424129Test {

    @Test
    fun `when full products required then list of full products received`() {
        val tested = SO64424129()

        val testSubscription = tested.getFullProducts().test()

        testSubscription.await()
        testSubscription.assertValue { listOfProducts ->
            listOfProducts.containsAll(listOf("1 PI: 1", "2 PI: 2", "3 PI: 3", "4 PI: 4"))
        }
        testSubscription.assertNoErrors()
    }
}
```

Interesting parts:

1. `getProducts()` returns a list of "product ids" with some delay to imitate real API
2. `getProductInfo()` returns single product info. For the sake of simplicity, I just convert the given ID to String `"PI: $productId"`, but you can do whatever you want.
3. Create `Observable` what emits a given list of ids as single items (one by one).
4. Combine id (`Product`) and product info string representation (`InfoProduct` )
5. `toList()` waits for `Complete` event, combine all of the emitted `ProductInfo`'s, and emits them as a single list.